# Control flow statements in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fetching data from a table on the basis of few parameters which are used in a where clause for filter criteria. The Parameters are number of days and customer name (@days and @customer name). Below are the things which I want to achieve.

1. if the user enters the number of days then it should fetch the data from current day to the entered day and if the user has not given any value to that parameter then it should take by default 5 days prior to the current date. For example let us say user passing the value @day=6 then filter criteria will be:

`where lastupdateddate between getdate() - 6`

and if user does not pass any value to parameter is should take default 5 days

```
where lastupdateddate between getdate() - 5
```

2. If the user provides the customer name then it should take that name in where clause. If the customer does not pass any name then it should return all customers available in column as default.

Comment: Hi Guys, Any help on above...much needed.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't give enough information for good answer but you should be able to do this with the null coalescing operator of whatever variant of SQL you're using.

eg) where lastupdatedate between getdate() and getdate() - nvl(@days,5)

For the customer name, just coalesce to the column value

where custname = nvl(@customer, custname)

Comment: I'm impressed you were able to deduce that to give an answer. Amazing.

Comment: `nvl()` is not valid SQL Server function name.  You need to use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()`

Comment: HI Levesque,

Thank you so much for your quick reply ..i tried your code but i think nvl function not supported in sql server 2008 .

Comment: Be careful if custname is potentially null. `(custname = @customer or @customer is null)` is essentially the same but allows the nulls to pass too.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following...

**UPDATED**  -- Using DATEADD() Function

```
WHERE CustomerName = CASE WHEN @Customer IS NOT NULL THEN @customername ELSE CustomerName END 
AND lastupdateddate BETWEEN getdate() and DATEADD(DAY, ISNULL(@int, 5) * -1,  GETDATE())
```

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Operand data type datetime is invalid for minus operator.
 getting this error..

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Odd.... but I have updated my answer to use DATEADD function that should correct for that error

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Operand data type datetime is invalid for minus operator.

Comment: same error again with updated code

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Operand data type datetime is invalid for minus operator.

Comment: If you remove everything from the `WHERE` clause relating to lastupdateddate do you get the same error?  It's hard to believe that you're getting an "_invalid for minus operator_" from the **DATEADD()** function

Comment: If you remove everything from the `WHERE` clause relating to lastupdateddate do you get the same error?